# Is there any possibility of Van der Waal forces being cumulative?

Tags: forces, physical-chemistry, interactions, molecules

Is there any possibility of Van der Waal forces being cumulative? I have been thinking about this for a long time and have never came across an answer.

Comment: What do you mean by a force being cumulative?

Comment: If the force is able to strengthen by the addition of more objects is what i mean of being cumulative.

Comment: You mean the interaction force between two objects would increase by adding more objects around them?

Comment: Yes, as well as the force of the all of the objects being added

Comment: Welcome to the difficulty of many body physics.

Comment: do you know any example of cumulative force in nature?

Answer (score 0):

Van Der Waal forces are forces between-

> force between permanent dipoles (Keesom force)
>
> force between a permanent dipole and a corresponding induced dipole
>   (Debye force)
>
> force between instantaneously induced dipoles (London dispersion
>   force).

As you may have learned or may learn in future classes dipoles are made of charges and electrostatic forces(forces between charges, somewhat similar to gravitaional forces if you havent heard about them) acts between charges. This force is conservative so Van der Waal forces **are conservative.**

Another method to prove-
If they are not conservative that means work is done SHM of atoms which means atoms continue to lose energy which is not possible.

Comment: The question was not about the force being conservative.